# How to reduce table dimension based on column name

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a table that has a format along the lines of

```
Class1 0.438 0.441 0.442 0.444 0.545 0.546 0.548 0.609 0.651 0.652 0.655 
  DAWO     2     2     0     1     0     0     0     1     1     5     1  
  DRWO     1     1     3     1     1     1     1     0     0     1     0   
  DHWO     1     2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

I would like to reduce the dimensions of the table by merging the columns based on columns name & adding the values. E.g

```
Class1    0.4   0.5   0.6 
  DAWO     5     0     8      
  DRWO     6     3     1    
  DHWO     3     0     0
```

How is this possible?
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="      0.438 0.441 0.442 0.444 0.545 0.546 0.548 0.609 0.651 0.652 0.655
DAWO     2     2     0     1     0     0     0     1     1     5     1
DRWO     1     1     3     1     1     1     1     0     0     1     0
DHWO     1     2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   ", check.names=F)
```

Note that I've not copied the text `Class1`, so that the `DAW0`, etc, are row names in the original set.

First, take a transpose to help with an `aggregate`:

```
tx <- as.data.frame(t(x))
```

These are the cuts.  Assumes that the values are between 0 and 1.  Adjust as necessary.

```
tx$bin <- cut(as.numeric(rownames(tx)), breaks=seq(0,1,.1))
```

Add up the values, set the names, and transpose back again:

```
xx <- aggregate(.~bin, data=tx, FUN=sum)
rownames(xx) <- xx$bin
t(xx[-1])
##      (0.4,0.5] (0.5,0.6] (0.6,0.7]
## DAWO         5         0         8
## DRWO         6         3         1
## DHWO         3         0         0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another alternative. Using "x" from @Matthew's answer, you can use `strtim` to create your categories from your names, and `sapply` across those to aggregate.

```
mymatch <- strtrim(names(x), 3)
sapply(unique(mymatch), function(y) rowSums(x[, mymatch == y, drop = FALSE]))
#      0.4 0.5 0.6
# DAWO   5   0   8
# DRWO   6   3   1
# DHWO   3   0   0
```

Alternatively, using your original data, you just need to be a little bit careful about remembering to drop your "Class1" column when taking the `rowSums`:

```
mymatch <- strtrim(names(mydf), 3)[-1]
cbind(mydf[1], 
      sapply(unique(mymatch), 
             function(y) rowSums(mydf[-1][, mymatch == y, drop = FALSE])))
#   Class1 0.4 0.5 0.6
# 1   DAWO   5   0   8
# 2   DRWO   6   3   1
# 3   DHWO   3   0   0
```

Finally, there is the classic "reshape2" approach that involves a `melt` and `*cast`:

```
> library(reshape2)
> Stacked <- melt(mydf)
Using Class1 as id variables
> dcast(Stacked, Class1 ~ strtrim(variable, 3), fun.aggregate=sum)
  Class1 0.4 0.5 0.6
1   DAWO   5   0   8
2   DHWO   3   0   0
3   DRWO   6   3   1
```

For the last two examples, `mydf` is defined as:

```
mydf <- structure(list(Class1 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("DAWO", 
"DHWO", "DRWO"), class = "factor"), `0.438` = c(2L, 1L, 1L), 
    `0.441` = c(2L, 1L, 2L), `0.442` = c(0L, 3L, 0L), `0.444` = c(1L, 
    1L, 0L), `0.545` = c(0L, 1L, 0L), `0.546` = c(0L, 1L, 0L), 
    `0.548` = c(0L, 1L, 0L), `0.609` = c(1L, 0L, 0L), `0.651` = c(1L, 
    0L, 0L), `0.652` = c(5L, 1L, 0L), `0.655` = c(1L, 0L, 0L)), 
.Names = c("Class1", "0.438", "0.441", "0.442", "0.444", "0.545", "0.546", 
"0.548", "0.609", "0.651", "0.652", "0.655"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```